# Ember Data TypeError during routing

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm getting this JS error while trying to use Ember routing:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object <DS.Store:ember215> has no method 'create' ember-data-latest.js:3677
    Ember.onLoad.app.registerInjection.injection ember-data-latest.js:3677
    Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend.initialize ember-latest.js:10381
    Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend.initialize ember-latest.js:10380
    Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend.initialize ember-latest.js:10379
    (anonymous function) app.js:6
```

This is with the latest Ember.js and Ember Data from GitHub today (the master version, not the release versions). I'm aware that using the current release version can cause similar issues, but so far this seems unusual.

Looking back at those lines, it appears the Ember routing code calls an Ember Data function, and that causes the error (and prevents routing from working properly).

Are there any solutions to this yet?

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/bkjT4/2/

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 4,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  root: Ember.State.extend({
    index: Ember.State.extend({
      route: '/'
    })
  })
});

App.router = App.Router.create({
    location: 'history' // does the same with hash
});

App.initialize(App.router);
```

​

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle with more code? You can use this as starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/PjbpL/

Comment: Done - http://jsfiddle.net/bkjT4/2/. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, the issue about the `has no method create()` is because you named your store `App.Store` (uppercase String "Store") and it is an instance. The convention in Ember.js is that you name classes `UpperCase` and instances `lowerCase` (see a good blog post by [the emberist](http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html)). This is an issue because in ember-data there is an injection registered, which automatically instantiates a `Store` class, if it is defined, see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/0047d674391652da82596bd5f7a84c7cb216610e/packages/ember-data/lib/system/application_ext.js#L9-11). Long story short: if you change it to either `App.store = Ember.Store.create({...})` or `App.Store = Ember.Store.extend({...})` this issue is solved.

After this has been solved, another problem arises: you are using `Ember.State` inside your `Ember.Router` where you should use `Ember.Route` instead. So the final code looks like this, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/5Y2PX/:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 4,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
});

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/'
    })
  })
});

App.router = App.Router.create({
    location: 'history'
});

App.initialize(App.router);
```

​

Comment: Thanks! That broken code was actually from the Rails generator, which I guess hasn't been updated.

Comment: Hmm, strange. But as far as I know alls this stuff is going to be fixed soon.